# Postgresql WAL on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm running Postgres 8.4 on Windows XP and I'm wondering if it is possible to move the WAL to a different disk? I have looked all over the place and can only find documentation on how to do this on Linux.

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create a windows symbolic link, which is called a "junction point" to do that. There are articles on google/wikipedia that will tell you how to create those :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was always under the impression that symlinks were not possible in windows.

In case anyone else needs this, I used this tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Thanks Magnus!

Comment: I'd like to add one more comment to this just in case it helps someone else. Say your pgdata directory is on drive D and you want to move your WAL to drive C. To get this working:
1) Shut down postgres. 
2) Make a backup of D:\pgdata\pg_xlog.
3) Now copy D:\pgdata\pg_xlog over to C:\pg_xlog
4) Now delete D:\pgdata\pg_xlog 
5) Unzip the junction program from above into D:\pgdata
6) Open cmd window inside D:\pgdata and run this command: junction -s pg_xlog C:\pg_xlog
7) Now right click on C:\pg_xlog folder and give postgres user permissions on the folder.
8) Restart Server!